# Is there a package that offers a function which transform a function to accept null as first argument?

Tags: r, function, package, null, purrr

I have made this function which seems useful:

```
nullify <- function(fn) function(...) {
 args <- list(...)
 if(is.null(args[[1]])) NULL else fn(...)
}
```

Here is an example of usage:

```
require(purrr)
list_1 <- NULL
list_2 <-flatten(list_1)
```

raises an error that you can manage like that:

```
list_2 <- (nullify(flatten))(list_1)
```

instead of:

```
list_2 <- if(is.null(list_1)) NULL else flatten(list_1)
```

---

I bet there is already that kind of function in some package, maybe rlang? But i cannot find one.

Comment: The error caused is not because of `NULL` but rather because `flatten` does not accept atomic vectors, but rather accepts generic ones. eg `flatten(1:5)` should raise an error. Probably you need to do `list_1 <- list(NULL)` then do `flatten(list_1)` this should run with no error